# fatal error: allegro5\allegro.h: No such file or directory yet found on cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, allegro5

So I did a game on Visual Studio long ago. 2 years ago I uploaded the sources to github [NEGU93/ForbiddenDesert](https://github.com/NEGU93/ForbiddenDesert) just to have it there. Now I changed from windows to linux and I wanted to go back and compile this game for linux.

I remember I used allegro for the GUI so I installed it following this steps [Installing Allegro 5](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_Git/Linux/Debian). When I coded the game I remember downloading an allegro prepared for Visual Studio directly so I didn't have any problems.

I created a CMakeLists.txt (never did that before, so I am quite new in that area):

```
# Specify the minimum version for CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# projects name
project(ForbiddenDesert)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)  # enable C++11 standard
# Set the output folder where your program will be created
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
# Finds Allegro using pkgconfig, so it must be configured correctly
find_package(Allegro5 REQUIRED)
# Set include and lib dirs.
include_directories(${ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(FD_LIBS ${LIBS} ${OBJC_LIBRARIES} ${ALLEGRO_LIBRARIES})


# The following folder will be included
# include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
# include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "*.h"
        "*.cpp"
        )

add_executable(forbidden ${all_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(forbidden ${FD_LIBS})
```

I am using a file named `FindAllegro5.cmake` inside a folder named `cmake/`. The file is a copy of [eruta/FindAllegro5.cmake](https://github.com/beoran/eruta/blob/master/cmake/FindAllegro5.cmake).

When running `cmake .` I get the following:

```
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'allegro-5'
--   Found allegro-5, version 5.2.4
-- Found Allegro5: /usr/lib/liballegro.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_image.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_font.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_primitives.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_ttf.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_audio.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_dialog.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_memfile.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_acodec.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_color.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_main.so;/usr/lib/liballegro_physfs.so
```

So far so good. Yet, when I run `make`

```
In file included from /home/ubuntu/Documents/GitHub/ForbiddenDesert/Button.h:5:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Documents/GitHub/ForbiddenDesert/ArcheologistButton.h:4,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Documents/GitHub/ForbiddenDesert/ArcheologistButton.cpp:1:
/home/ubuntu/Documents/GitHub/ForbiddenDesert/allegro.h:5:10: fatal error: allegro5\allegro.h: No such file or directory
 #include <allegro5\allegro.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/forbidden.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/forbidden.dir/ArcheologistButton.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/forbidden.dir/ArcheologistButton.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/forbidden.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/forbidden.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've seen that the `FindAllegro5.cmake` has:

```
# Include dir
find_path(Allegro5_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES allegro5/allegro5.h
  PATHS ${Allegro5_PKGCONF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

So I changed the include to `#include <allegro5/allegro5.h>` but still no solution.

I haven't been able to find the solution (I've found plenty of information about the "fatal error: allegro5\allegro.h: No such file or directory" but haven't found one that applies to my case).

---

So I installed allegro with the following: [Quickstart Allegro](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro_wiki/wiki/Quickstart) and then I created the `hello.c` file and compiled it as it says there (`gcc hello.c -o hello $(pkg-config allegro-5 allegro_font-5 --libs --cflags)`) and it worked. So the problem will be how to add those flags to the cmakelists.txt

So I tried:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} $(pkg-config allegro-5 allegro_font-5 allegro_primitives-5 allegro_ttf-5 allegro_image-5 allegro_audio-5 allegro_acodec-5  --libs --cflags)")
```

But still didn't work.

---

Running `find /usr/ -name "allegro*"`
I found the header `allegro5.h` on `/usr/include/allegro5/allegro5.h` and some other files on `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`.
So I did:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( /usr/include/allegro5 )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(  /usr/lib/pkgconfig )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(game liballegro.a )
```

Still not working.

---

I tried adding the libraries directly from the build I compiled from the source code on github (following the info I found here [Allegro and CMake](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/639698-allegro-and-cmake-so-close-but-wont-compile/)) and still didn't work:

```
#Include Allegro
include_directories(/home/ubuntu/Documents/GitHub/allegro5/build/include)
include_directories(/home/ubuntu/Documents/GitHub/allegro5/build/lib/Headers)
link_directories(/home/ubuntu/Documents/GitHub/allegro5/build/lib)
#connect all the libraries you need
set(game_LIBS liballegro.so liballegro_dialog.so liballegro_image.so)
target_link_libraries(game ${game_LIBS})
```

Comment: **Never** set `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variable. The variable should be treated as *read-only* even while CMake doesn't enforce that.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Tsyvarev. I did based on [Tutorial cmake a begginer guide](https://tuannguyen68.gitbooks.io/learning-cmake-a-beginner-s-guide/content/chap1/chap1.html). But I could remove it then.

Comment: So bad that tutorials show the wrong usage. By the way, setting `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variable could actually add some weird errors, I suggest you recheck your code without that setting. (Do not forget to remove `CMakeCache.txt` file from build directory before a new attempt). For the case this won't help, what is content of `ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR` variable which you use in `include_directories` call? For check that you may add the line `"message(ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR: ${ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR}")` after the `find_package()` call.

Comment: So I commented the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` as you said an added that line and got the following: `ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR:/usr/include`. I do have `allegro5/` folder in that path that contains an `allegro5.h`. I changed my code to do `<allegro5/allegro5.h>` instead of `<allegro5/allegro.h>` but I'm having the same error.

Comment: Hm, this looks strange. So, what **exact path separator** is used in the C code? The error message contains backslash (`#include <allegro5\allegro.h>`), but you tell that you change `<allegro5/allegro.h>` to <allegro5/allegro5.h>. As far as I know, gcc (default compiler on Linux) uses forward slash `/` only and doesn't understand backslash for include files.

Comment: It worked! It was a problem with the back slash! I just put `/` and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Ubuntu I would just install allegro with `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install liballegro5-dev
```

Then the includes would be at the right place (`/usr/include/allegro5/...`)

You say you installed allegro, but I'm not too sure whether it would be the same as from a package. If it was from a build, it is often that the default installation directory is `/usr/local` instead of `/usr`. So the includes would be in `/usr/local/include/allegro5/...`

That being said, your `include()` command in cmake is correct:

```
include_directories(${ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

However, your libraries handling is completely wrong. You never have to change `LD_FLAGS`. (At least, in the last 6 or 7 years I've used cmake, I never had a need.) Instead, you want to use the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). Something like this:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ALLEGRO_LIBRARIES})
```

It will work within (as in after) a `project(...)`.

If you want to verify that the variables are correctly named, you may use the [`message()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html) command. Some libraries use names such as `NAME_LIBRARY` or `NAME_INCLUDE_PATH`. They should follow the proper naming convention, but nothing forces them to, so you often find some funkiness there.

The following will print a message out:

```
message("allegro libraries = " ${ALLEGRO_LIBRARIES})
```

If the variable name is not correct (or the library was not found), you will see nothing. If you got it right, it will show you the variable libraries. I would imagine that is right, but the `LD_FLAGS` was probably what you got wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I did what you said. I still had the problems but in the end I changed the `\` for a `/` and it work. However my current working version is with your suggestions for the CMakeLists.txt file. I've also installed via de `apt-get`. So I'm not sure if my older version of CMake would have worked.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you're making progress at least. And yes, backslashes (\\) in paths do not work well with gcc/g++.